# Interrogating Outlook across a peer-to-peer network?

Tags: outlook, p2p

Eventually we may have Active Directory in place but until then, is there any way I can interrogate a user's Outlook across the network and find out, for instance, what PST and OST files they are connected to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer by @mmcg to [the same question posted on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/55893/how-do-i-find-out-what-pst-files-users-have-attached-to-their-outlook-accounts)